# Pass all attributes to an element in Jade

Tags: pug

If you created a mixin like so:

```
mixin my-wonderful-form()
    form
        fieldset
            block
```

and wanted to pass all attributes specified against the mixin to the form element, is there a way to do it without specifying each one, so that:

```
my-wonderful-form.wonderform#wonderform(action='/', method='POST')
```

would effectively do:

```
mixin my-wonderful-form()
    form(
        action=attributes.action,
        class=attributes.class,
        id=attributes.id,
        method=attributes.method
    )
        fieldset
            block
```

for me automatically?

More importantly it means mixins for elements such as forms will not have to redefine every available attribute on a form.

The alternative will be a maintenance nightmare if a project starts using data- attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you pass the attributes variable (thanks to http://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/):

```
mixin my-wonderful-form()
    form(attributes)
        fieldset
            block
```

or if form was a mixin:

```
mixin my-wonderful-form()
    +form(attributes=attributes)
        fieldset
            block
```